# Save information of users while they are login or in another word while they are using the app (android app)

Tags: android, android-sqlite

am developing an android application with SQLite database, the application is for the university that shows schedules of students as well as instructors, also show the absence of students ...etc, the problems that I faced are, first, I do not know how I show schedules of students as well as instructors 
second, how I execute the query to select from multiple tables that saved in SQLite database
third, what is the method that used to perform download and upload files from/to app
thank you

Comment: Can you please let us know what you have done so far? What is the error are you getting?

Comment: the problem that i beginner in android so i don't know how i solve the above problems